# How to add sub sub menus in wix websites

Tags: javascript, json, velo

How we can add sub sub menus in wix website like as below screenshot.

[multiple-sub-sub-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBflf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-request-creating-sub-subpages-expandable-menus said that:

> Currently, you cannot add sub-subpages to your site's menu to create
> an expandable menu. As an alternative, you can use buttons to link to
> hidden pages (the sub-subpages). That way visitors will not be able to
> find the page in your site's menu, rather they will need to click a
> button on the relevant sub-page to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing to say that as of March 7, 2023, this feature remains unavailable despite multiple user requests to add it. The closest alternative I have found involves some custom page code described here, though it does not accomplish what you (and I) want which is a sub sub menu: https://www.wix.com/velo/example/mega-menu

Unfortunately the only solution as of now is to program your own menu or rearrange your menu to avoid needing a "sub sub menu" structure.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to update, in case anyone was stuck trying to implement sub-sub menus, it is possible to do so in Wix Editor, only for Horizontal Menus (https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/menu/introduction).

To do so, add a Horizontal Menu (Add Elements > Menu & Anchors > Horizontal Menu) and click on the Menu's settings to toggle Advanced menu. Upon doing so, while managing menus, you'll now be able to add submenus within submenu items and can even utilize the mega menus as linked by [benq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663815/22680980). As these can be tied to the horizontal menu element, you can place them in the headers/footers without having to allocate the large amount of space required by the static Mega menu example that Wix gave.

Note that Themed Horizontal Menus do not count as Horizontal Menus, for whatever reason. Also note that if you wish to do this, you'll have to manage menus by yourself (Wix will no longer auto add new pages to the menu, although IMO it's a small price to pay for better UX)